# Image Source not found

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am trying to resize the image using intervention class but keep getting this error.
`Image source not readable`
My code is:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $imagePath = $data['avatar']->store('/uploads', 'public' );
        $image = Image::make(storage_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(500,500);
        $image -> save();
        // dd(storage_path("{$imagePath}"));

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'avatar' => $data['imageArray'],
        ]);
    }
```

dd `storage_path("$imagePath")` sends me the complete link like this. 
`"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Krenovate-TrainersApp\trainers\storage\uploads/WZr9RtzCk5phX28AgtOyf1VyFmkQNdnBAdXDG8a8.jpeg"`

Can't make it to work.

Comment: `Image::make(storage_path($imagePath))->fit(500,500);` try this ?

Comment: same error again!!

Comment: I think, maybe the problem is  with permission

Comment: How can I resolve it?